# How do I make error notices in this ruby form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

How can I make an error notice when somebody leaves spaces empty, etc...

I tried enumerous codes and they either didn't work or failed... I even installed a gem but nothing worked until now... please help with ideas/solutions

```
<div class="jumbotron"
    <div class="container">

    <h2>Signup</h2>


<%= form_for :user, url: '/users' do |f| %>
  Número de Empregado: <br>
  <%= f.number_field :NumeroEmpregado %><br>
  Primeiro e Último Nome: <br>
  <%= f.text_field :nome %><br>
  Password: <br>
  <%= f.password_field :password %><br>
  Confirmação Password: <br>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %><br>


  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>

    </div>
</div>

<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.new(user_params)
    if user.save
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to '/'
    else
    flash[:error] = 'invalid value'

    end
  end

private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:NumeroEmpregado, :nome, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

Comment: I suggest you to generate a scaffold and see how the form works. See this link http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#displaying-validation-errors-in-views for showing validation errors:

Comment: Semi-off topic, but you should fix your indentation and alignment of `div`/`form` blocks. The `<% end %>` should be placed 3 lines up - and this mistake would have been obvious, had you indented the code properly.

Comment: Done @TomLord thanks for the observation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Active Record Validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html).

If you have a model called User, then you can specify which attributes to validate for presence using the `validates` method and setting the `presence` to `true`, this will check if the field on the form has been filled, also if has only whitespaces.

For instance:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :nome, presence: true
  ...
```

For your controller:

```
def create 
  user = User.new(user_params) 
  if user.save 
    session[:user_id] = user.id 
    redirect_to '/' 
  else 
    flash[:error] = 'invalid value' 
    redirect_to new_user_path
  end 
end
```

Redirect to the new user path with `flash[:error]` as "invalid value".

For your view:

```
<% if flash[:error] %>
  <div class="error">
    <%= flash[:error] %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I already have this done with a def user_params that checks if you submited all 4 things I just want to make a notice when you don't!!

I have it like this atm: `else
      redirect_to '/signup'

    end`

Comment: Add your controller to the question.

Comment: Done it! you can check now

Comment: Don't you redirect when the user isn't saved?, check the updated answer.

Comment: I used to have `redirect_to '/signup'` after the flash notice, and the flash notice still doesn't appear...

Comment: It depends if you have the way to show the `flash` in the view, do you?

Comment: Maybe that's it! How do I make a way to show it in the view?

Comment: Just check if `flash[:error]` has a value and print it, see the udpdated answer.

Answer (score 4):

- Rails only can validate when you submitted your form. In this case, you can check out [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html).
- In other case, if you want immediately show validate message when user enter into input, you must validate it by using Javascript. You also can use [Jquery validation plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) to do that.

Hope its help :)

Answer (score 1):

you should use jquery validations if you want to check if the field is empty type validations before submit https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/ follow this link.

Or if you are ok with validating fields on submit then in create or update action of your controller you can check from the params if that field is empty. then you can show flash messages like this

```
flash[:notice] = 'valid value'
flash[:error] = 'invalid value'
```

Or you can add model level validations on that fields http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html here

Comment: I did this : 
`def create
    user = User.new(user_params)
    if user.save
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to '/'
    else
    flash[:error] = 'invalid value'

    end
  end`

got this error: `No template found for UsersController#create, rendering head :no_content`

Comment: def create
        user = User.new(user_params)
        if user.save
            session[:user_id] = user.id
            redirect_to root_path, notice: 'valid value'
        else
            flash[:error] = 'invalid value'
            redirect_to action: "new"
        end
end
you forgot to mention redirect path in your else part